# How can I set additional state with fetch from Api?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have custom hook in which I am able set data, but additionally I want to build columns from response, but I get empty array of >>  columns  << which is return by hook before initialisation.

```
const urls: string[] = [
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos",
];

const useTable = (idurl: number, actualcategory: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Data>();
  const current = useRef<Function>();
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState<Column[]>();
  let objcolumn: Column[] = [];

  const loadDatabase = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(urls[idurl]);
    const d = await response.json();

    objcolumn = [
      ...Object.keys(d[0]).map((t: string) => {
        let d: Column = { col: { title: t, disp: true } };
        return d;
      }),
    ];
    setColumns(objcolumn);
   };
  current.current = loadDatabase;
  useEffect(() => {
    current.current && current.current();

  }, [actualcategory]);
  return [data && data[actualcategory], columns] as const;
};

export { useTable };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant first initial value it is standart behavior because your hook has async operation and while operation not resolved hook returns default value.

If you meant second returned value, you can fix it with reduce number of state. Every state change lead to new render.

You can memoize columns value, no need to save it in new state.

And using a lot of logical operators may lead to unexpected boolean values.

I added `any` types because in your code types didnt presented. And changed some names of variables for better readability.

```
const useTable = (idurl: number, actualcategory: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<any>({})

  const loadDatabase = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(urls[idurl])
    const result = await response.json()

    setData(result)
  }

  const ref = useRef<Function>(loadDatabase)

  const columns = useMemo(() => {
    return data[0]
      ? [
          ...Object.keys(data[0]).map((t: string) => {
            let d: any = { col: { title: t, disp: true } }
            return d
          }),
        ]
      : []
  }, [data])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current()
    }
  }, [actualcategory, idurl])

  return [data[actualcategory] ? data[actualcategory] : [], columns] as const
}
```

Using of useRef unnecessary there. You can call function in useEffect. But maybe ref is used in other not presented code so I have not changed ref.

This code works fine. At first render hook returns initial values and after resolving of async request return new values. Simple reprsentation in codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-feather-2tyfld?file=/src/App.tsx

Write a comment if it works the way you want

Comment: everything works fine, thanks!

Comment: @arturnowakowski nice, you can choose best answer))